# How to get rid of empty values when adding string in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, function

I have something like this:

```
public function options()
      {
         $out = '';
         $docs = $this->getAll();;
         foreach($docs as $key => $doc) {
             $out .= ',{"label" : "' . $doc['name'] . '", "value" : "' . $doc['id'] .'"}';
         }
         return $out;
      }
```

It gives me a list of options from the DB, but it also gives me a null value at the top.

if I write it like this:

```
public function options()
     {
         //$out = '';
         $docs = $this->getAll();;
         foreach($docs as $key => $doc) {
             $out = '';
             $out .= '{"label" : "' . $doc['name'] . '", "value" : "' . $doc['id'] .'"}';
         }
         return $out;
     }
```

It doesn't give me the null value but it only returns one value.

```
$out .= ',{"label" : "' . $doc['name'] . '", "value" : "' . $doc['id'] .'"}';
```

In this line if I don't add an `,` it gives me an error message, This because I have `$out = '';` at the top. Now can you guys give me an idea how can I get all the values from the DB without the empty value at the beginning.

I also have another question , why we use `;;` (double semicolon) in this code:

```
 $docs = $this->getAll();;
```

Comment: The double semicolon shouldn't be there. While it won't produce a syntax error, it's incorrect.

Comment: And as someone has answered below, PHP has built-in function to deal with JSON - json_encode and json_decode

Answer (score 1):

test $out to see if it has any length, if so add the comma and the line, otherwise just set it to be the line:

```
$out="";
foreach($docs as $key=>$doc){
    if(strlen($out)){
        $out.=',{"label" : "' . $doc['name'] . '", "value" : "' . $doc['id'] .'"}';
    }else{
        $out='{"label" : "' . $doc['name'] . '", "value" : "' . $doc['id'] .'"}';
    }
}
```

as to your other question, er, you wrote the code, so why did you put a double semi-colon?

Comment: I am debugging some other developers code and I can see this double semicolon in lots of places, So I wondered what is going on there as I never come up with double semicolon yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to build JSON. First create an array, and use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) instead to hold the individual values, and using [join](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) to concatenate them together.

```
public function options()
{
     $docs = $this->getAll();
     // Create an empty array
     $items = array();
     foreach($docs as $key => $doc) {
         // "Push" an item to the end of the array
         $items[] = '{"label" : "' . $doc['name'] . '", "value" : "' . $doc['id'] .'"}';
     }
     // Join the contents together
     $out = join(",", $items);
     return $out;
}
```

Also, the double semi-colon is completely unnecessary.